# Code will not accept Freesans as a resource file

Tags: java, unicode, itext

I am trying to put mathmatical symbols into my PDF. The error, java.io.IOException: resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf not found as file or resource.

```
public class CreateTable {
    public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {


        BaseFont bf = null;
        try {
            bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Font f = new Font(bf, 12);
        Document document = new Document();  // Whole page is consider as docuemnt so we need object .
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);  //Create Table Object

        //Adding alignment and cells with defining rows
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell("");
        table.addCell("Age \u00AC");
        table.addCell("Location");
        table.addCell("Anotherline");
        table.setHeaderRows(1);}
}
```

The file is in the resources folder and under fonts. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: can you unzip the generated jar file and see if your ttf indeed embedded inside?

Comment: It does not generate a file yet, only pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error it seems your program not getting file so throwing exception.

IOException has sub classes such as FileNotFoundException . Make sure file path is correct and resource directory has ttf file .

Comment: I thought I had the resources folder correct, but there seems to be two resource folders.